# Как MySQL сохраняет данные?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, типы, хранение-данных

Вопрос о том как MySQL занимает место на диске, и о правильном выборе типа данных.

Для примера будем считать что есть миллион статей, которые имеют заголовок и описание.

```
title: VARCHAR(250)
content: TEXT
```

Из этих статей:

- 30% имеют текст меньше 1000 символов
- 30% больше 1000 и меньше 5000
- остальные больше 5000

Если сделать 3 таблицы, и в каждой указать `content` равный нужной длинне, MySQL займёт меньше место на диске?

То есть MySQL резервирует место под каждый ряд?
Или занимает место только под те данные которые имеет на текущий момет?

Comment: Text занимает места ровно столько сколько самого текста в наличии... в самой таблице хранится "ссылка" на данные... это в простом и утрированном случае. Varchar(250) занимает фиксированный рвзмер. Сколько бы текста вы там не хранили.

Comment: `в простом и утрированном случае` это как?

Comment: Это значит для понимания вашего примера это значения не имеет. Текст во всех трех таблицах будет занимать +/-(на грани небольшой погрешности) одинаковое ккол-во места на диске

Comment: если хотите, оформите это как ответ, отмечу решением

Comment: Я с телефона, а на ответ этот текст не тянет. Возможно если увижу этот вопрос с компа и много позже - сделаю полноценный ответ о хранении BLOB и TEXT

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear Все типы переменной длины (т.е. blob и все символьные типы кроме char) хранятся в виде поля длины (1-4 байта в зависимости от типа данных), в котором собственно и указана текущая длина, за которым идет собственно текст. Т.е. если вы в поле text сохраните одну букву А, то на диске будет лежать 3 байта: 0x01 0x00 'A'. Это описано в документации MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html